# How can I define custom labels value when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multiclass-classification, tf.keras

my model is compiled with this code

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

During training, I got this error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).

My label are `1,2,3,4,5` which is `[1,5]` not `[0, 5)`.
How can I set labels for this model?

Comment: Subtract 1 from the labels before passing to the model.

Comment: does that mean sparse labels must be encode to 0 based index?

Comment: Yes; indices are all 0 based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode your labels into `[0, 4]`, which is zero-based, not one-based. This is because to recover class indices, the `argmax` function is used, for which the array index corresponding to the maximum value is returned, which will be zero-based.

Comment: some implementation and library allow labels input so I think there might be someway,thank you for mentioning argmax.