# ValueError: Missing data for input "input_2". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['y', 'x']. Expected the following keys: ['input_2']

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated

Following the previous code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428904/valueerror-layer-sequential-expects-1-inputs-but-it-received-10-input-tens) I am in process to evaluate the federated learning model and I got couple of issues.
This is the code for evaluation

```
central_test = test.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients()
test_data = central_test.map(reshape_data)

# function that accepts a server state, and uses 
#Keras to evaluate on the test dataset.
def evaluate(server_state):
  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  keras_model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]  
  )
  keras_model.set_weights(server_state)
  keras_model.evaluate(central_test)

server_state = federated_algorithm.initialize()
evaluate(server_state)
```

this is the error message

```
ValueError: Missing data for input "input_2". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['y', 'x']. Expected the following keys: ['input_2']
```

So what would be the problem here?
and is the use of the method `create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients` in its right place? since -as it is written in the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/building_your_own_federated_learning_algorithm)- used for **create a centralized evaluation dataset**. why do we need to use centralized dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test` dataset has a different format during evaluation. Try:

```
test_data = test.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients().map(reshape_data).batch(2)
test_data = test_data.map(lambda x: (x['x'], x['y']))

def evaluate(server_state):
  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  keras_model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]  
  )
  keras_model.set_weights(server_state)
  keras_model.evaluate(test_data)

server_state = federated_algorithm.initialize()
evaluate(server_state)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks!!! Can you tell me why did we use t]e function `create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients` since it is used to create centralized dataset? Also, why did we use `.batch(2)` not 1?

Comment: You can also use `batch(1)`.. I was just following the tutorial you linked .. it’s just an example